# How to copy metadata exported from mp3 file (with ffmpeg) int another mp3 file

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, mp3

I have 2 mp3 files with the same content but with different speed and volume level. I would like to copy the metadata from one to the other and **only** the metadata. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50580239/2235831), and was able to extract the metadata to a file. But now when I try to copy the metadata to the second file as described in that post, it copies the whole file as well. This then overwrites the audio itself as well as the metadata.

How can I **only** copy the metadata into the second file without copying the actual audio.

Comment: change `in.mp4` in the second command to the second audio file

Comment: @kesh Thanks this worked. BTW is there a way to just change the metadata without copying the whole file?

Comment: No. I'd look for another program for metadata processing. FFmpeg is not designed to do that.