# PHP FFmpeg metadata usage

Tags: php, ffmpeg, metadata

```
 shell_exec("d:/wamp/ffmpg/ffmpeg  -metadata title="Movie Title" -metadata year="2010"  -i $vaw  -b:v 64k  -bufsize 64k $mp3");
```

i need add meta data to new output file with utf8 chars in installed windows localhost.

How can i add metadata txt have you any examples for metadata.txt?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464617/retrieving-and-saving-media-metadata-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Yes i see ffmpeg -i input_video -f ffmetadata metadata.txt but where ise the output file? and how i convert  -bufsize 64k