# How to read a file's metadata in Python?

Tags: python, metadata

For instance, a video file's aspect ratio or the date of creation of a doc file.

**I'm specifically looking for video files and their resolution**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Comment: The Video files aspect ratio is not exactly metadata on the OS file level,decode it.

Comment: Depends on what metadata you want and the type of file.

Comment: There is no general way to obtain the data you want. You need to be specific and look up documentation for the format that you work with. E.g. `mkv` container have different format and set of tools than `avi` or `flv`.

Comment: Know of any such third party libraries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving and Saving media metadata using FFmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464617/retrieving-and-saving-media-metadata-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: @6502: ffmpeg is not the only (and perhaps not even the best) option out there, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Take a look at Extractor. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Extractor/0.5 Also hachoir: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata/1.3.3