# Extract geotags from video file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, video, geotagging

I want to get the geotags from a video and mark it on map. I've found [exif-js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) but this only works with images.

I've tried it with `ffmpeg`, [a server solution which works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473239/6771046), but the size of videos that I worked is about 1GB to 3GB.

Is it possible to do with Javascript instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For further research it might be easier to find an answer if the video format is known. Can you specify the video format, encoding, scaling, etc. in more detail?

Comment: Video files can be .mov, and  .mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers do not have built-in methods for extracting geotags from a video. With Web APIs you can only use [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) (use event [loadedmetadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata)) or [VideoPlaybackQuality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoPlaybackQuality).

Try using [ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js).

> This library provides FFmpeg builds ported to JavaScript using
>   Emscripten project. Builds are optimized for in-browser use: minimal
>   size for faster loading, asm.js, performance tunings, etc. Though they
>   work in Node as well.

Comment: OP could you get the location data from this? I have ffmpeg.js installed but the '-i' flag doesn't get me the location data. Would you mind sharing your ffmpeg 'command'

Comment: @SeanAye did you find a javascript library to extract geotags?