# How to extract location metadata from video using Javascript or react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to extract latitude and longitude of geo-referenced video, is there a way to extract those details in javascript using some javascript/react library?

Comment: Can you provide more specific details? Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230095/extract-geotags-from-video-file-with-javascript

Comment: @Julian I have tried ffmpeg.js but it doesn't work with react js. There were build errors. Can ffmpeg provide location metadata if we pass a video url to it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230095/extract-geotags-from-video-file-with-javascript
here the user couldn't access location metadata

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no way to extract this data on the web, its something in the binary file that browsers don't provide an interface for.