# How can I copy all metadata from one file to another automatically?

Tags: metadata, mp3, tagging, copying, flac

I have a collection of .mp3 files that have a lot of metadata on them, and a collection of those same tracks as .flac files with no metadata. I'd like to be able to simply copy the metadata from an .m03 file to its .flac cousin automatically. I don't care if I have to manually point the .flac to the corresponding .mp3, I just don't want to have to manually copy all of the metadata onto the .flac files as there are a lot of them.

Comment: `ffmpeg` can export and import metadata - https://stackoverflow.com/q/9464617/2670892

Comment: What's the command to do it though?